# Chrome HTML basic login not working with name and pass in URL

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have issue and I probably know that chrome blocks this feature, but here I am. I have a HTML5 video code, that plays video from secured server. Server uses only basic authentication. So, in source I have

```
<source src="http://username:pass@mydomain/test?profile=test" type="video/webm" />
```

In Firefox, everything works fine, I am not prompted to give username and password again. However, if I open site in Chrome, basic authentication window pops up and I have to re-enter username and password. Any idea how to do it?

Note: I know this is not secure at all, and it will be used in family only, I just want to make process simple.